# In eloquence there is magic explanation

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Can someone explain this line:

"In eloquence there is magic" from the hadith...

Narrated Buraydah ibn al-Hasib (RadhiAllahu 'anhu), I heard the Prophet of Allah ﷺ say:

> In eloquence there is magic, in knowledge ignorance, in poetry wisdom and in speech heaviness.

I searched the net but I still cannot understand what it means. Does it mean people use magic to become eloquent?

Comment: Please try to check this out... [Explanation](http://www.hadithgarden.com/2013/03/prophet-pbuh-said-in-eloquence-there-is.html) If still u don't understand, comment below

Answer (score 1):

The words **"Inna minnal-bayyan siHr"** = **"Indeed, in *bayyan* [eloquence/good style] is *sihr*"**

SiHr literally means trickery.  A person who knows how to talk eloquently can trick people into believing or disbelieving things that may or may not be true.

Just think about a salesman.  How he talks to you, or does is "pitch," matters on convincing you to buy the product.  Good salesmen are great at convincing people.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It could be a good thing too. Here is the story of this hadith and you can tell.
A group of notable figures from Tamim tribe went to prophet Muhammad to convert to Islam. The group led by Al-Zebriqan Ben Badr, who introduced himself to prophet Muhammad saying: "I am the master of Bani Tamim (Tamim clan), they obey me, I prevent them from oppression and return their rights". Then he he pointed his finger at Amr bin Al-Ahtham, and this person knows that about me. Amr said: "He prevents oppression on his close circle, and those who are around him obey him". Amr praised Al-Zebriqan less than Al-Zebriqan praised himself, which made Al-Zebriqan angry. So he said: "O messenger of god (means Muhammad), I swear he knew about me more than what he said. Nothing prevented him from speaking about it except envy". Amr responded insulting Al-Zebriqan: "I envy you? O messenger of god, I swear by god, his uncles (mother's family) evil (or low), he just became rich (nouveau riche), his father is idiot, and he is not regarded as the leader of Tamim". Prophet Muhammad did not like that Amr insulted Al-Zebriqan after praising him. Amr said: O messenger of God, I was true in what I said first, and I did not lie in what I said last. But I am a man. If I am satisfied, I say the best of what I know, and when I get angry, I say the worst thing I find." Then prophet Muhammad said: "There is magic in eloquence, There is magic in eloquence"

Comment: I would not interpret this as the Prophet (p.b.u.h) being positive saying "it's magic". Rather, I read it as negative.

Comment: Comment on contents